# "/admin" disappearing from URL after loading the view (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

After navigating to an admin view, `/admin` disappears out of the URL.

This is occurring for all routes nested inside `namespace :admin do`.

**Example:**

1. Visiting `http://localhost:3000/admin/universities` loads the view.
2. But then the URL in that view changes to `http://localhost:3000/universities`.
3. Refreshing the page without manually adding back in the `/admin`, results in "No route matches".

**Server Logs:**

```
Started GET "/admin/universities"
Processing by Admin::UniversitiesController#index as HTML
Rendered admin/universities/index.html.haml within layouts/admin
Rendering admin/universities/index.html.haml within layouts/admin
```

**Route:**

```
namespace :admin do
    ...
    get '/universities', to: 'universities#index', as: :university_index
    ...
end
```

**rake routes:**

```
admin_university_index GET   /admin/universities(.:format)    admin/universities#index
```

**Controller:**

```
class Admin::UniversitiesController < Admin::BaseController

  def index
    @universities = University.all
  end
end
```

I inherited the app and am having trouble figuring out why this is occuring. Has anyone else had experience with this before?

### UPDATE

Could this be caused by turbolinks?

### UPDATE

Per request, adding `admin/base_controller`

```
# /app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController

  before_action :admin_only
  layout "admin"

  private

    def admin_only
      unless current_user && current_user.role == 'admin'
        redirect_to login_url, :notice => "Unauthorized"
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: share result of `rake routes`

Comment: Added `rake routes` and a controller

Comment: Could you also share your `Admin::BaseController` please?

Comment: Added Admin::BaseController

Comment: Seems like javascript at play to me, what are you doing on the frontend?

Comment: Alot of  vanillaJS, jquery and turbolinks

Comment: Your problem is probably with JavaScript in my opinion. So please share that.

Comment: Can you help point me in the right direction - What part might you want to see? Its an app in production with thousands of lines of javascript...

Comment: Don't you know what parts are relevant to the page in question? You need to look up how JavaScript affects the window's address. E.g. `window.location`. I have a hunch that something like this is at play. The address is changed on load, and gives this failed refresh

Comment: Really appreciate the help! Unfortunately I inherited the app and don't have much of a background in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly seems like a problem which could be caused by Turbolinks. If you haven't already, you can try and narrow down the possibilities by starting up a dev server and removing the Turbolinks gem. If you don't experience the problem then you'll know it has something to do with Turbolinks.

While it seems inevitable that this is caused by Javascript, you can test this by disabling javascript execution in your browser, visiting an admin page, and checking to see if the address updates.

Turbolinks documentation: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Comment: Removing turbolinks 5 fixed the issue. But given that I need to use turbolinks, I just need to figure out how/where to fix something now.

Comment: Looking at the Turbolinks docs, the navigation and "Running javascript when page loads" sections seem like obvious places that might give you a hint. You can try searching your code base for `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load"` text (or some variation), to find any events firing when the page loads. Maybe the app's admin pages used to not be namespaced with `admin` and the old (non-namespaced) links are hardcoded into some function thats firing on page load. Just one possibility

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Singular Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) where when you define the route as:

```
get '/universities', to: 'universities#index', as: :university_index
```

It effectively changes your route to `/universities`.

Instead review [Controller Namespaces and Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing). To achieve `/admin/universities you should look to change your`routes.rb` file to something like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :universities, only: [:index] # Creates index only route
end
```

Comment: Singular resources is interesting and I learned something there. Unfortunately, `resources :universities, only: [:index]` result in the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm, I assume you restarted your local server?

Comment: Unfortunately yea.